# Running silent install and uninstall without any parameters in Installshield

Tags: windows-installer, silent

I have developed a basic MSI package in Installshield. To make it install silently, I have included the MSI command line argument "/qb+" while building only. This installs it silently as expected.

However when I execute the same EXE again with the intention of uninstalling the previously installed components, it actually does a Reinstall or Repair but not a Uninstall. I would like to launch the same EXE for installation and then for uninstallation. Is it possible?

Regards,
Abhijit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because maintenance is performed for an already installed package by default, and default maintenance does nothing. You might be able to hack this with an approach similar to [How to get msiexec to install and/or reinstall as necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799713/how-to-get-msiexec-to-install-and-or-reinstall-as-necessary/5805381#5805381) but instead of using REINSTALL, try setting REMOVE and clearing it when [UILevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) > 3 OR NOT Installed.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, you may also want to condition against some of the other properties being set (for instance add `OR REINSTALL`, `OR ADDLOCAL`, `OR ADDSOURCE`, etc., to the condition). And as Glytzhkof says, this is unusual, and should probably not be used in a widely distributed package.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if this is an EXE for testing purposes or for public release. If it is for public release I would **not** change how it generally works in line with the "principle of least astonishment". In other words, the user should know what to expect.

I generally avoid the setup.exe launchers and favour a single, compressed MSI file. It will install and uninstall quicker because it doesn't run all the launch logic of the setup.exe (checking any pre-requisites, checking the Installshield engine, unknown Installshield stuff - God knows what they are doing in all the slowness), and it will provide users with a context menu in explorer so then can right click the MSI and select "Uninstall" for easy uninstall of the package.